# The text in float right is displayed in the left side

Tags: html, css-float, text-align

I'm getting trouble in the display of the following code. I'm concerned with dividing the `<div class="contectCode">` to two `<div class="left">` and `<div class="right">`. So, some of the cases of switch should be displayed in the left and some in the right.

```
<?php

        $xml = simplexml_load_file("Profiles.xml");

        foreach($xml->children() as $Developer){ 
        echo '<div class="contectCode" style="height: 260px;">';

            echo '<div class="left" style="width:365px;">';
            echo '<b>' . $Developer['name'] . '</b>';
            echo '</div><br/>';

            echo '<div class="left"  style="width:365px; float:left; text-align:left;">';
            echo '<p><b><i>Communications with you</i></b></p>';
            echo '</div>';

            echo '<div class="right" style="width:365px; float:right; text-align:left;">';
            echo '<p><b><i>Communications with other developers </i></b></p>';
            echo '</div>';
            foreach($Developer->children() as $factor){

                switch ($factor->getName()){

                    case "trust":
                        echo '<div class="left" style="width:365px; float:left; text-align:left;">';
                        if($Developer['gender'] == "Male")
                            echo '<p>You have selected (trusted) him to help you ' . $factor . ' times</p><br/>';
                        else
                            echo '<p>You have selected (trusted) her to help you ' . $factor . ' times</p><br/>';
                        echo '</div>';
                        break;
                    case "response":
                        echo '<div class="left" style="width:365px; float:left; text-align:left;">';
                        if($Developer['gender'] == "Male")
                            echo '<p>He hes responded to your help request ' . $factor . ' times</p><br/>';
                        else
                            echo '<p>She has responded to your help request ' . $factor . ' times</p><br/>';
                        echo '</div>';
                        break;
                    case "indegreeOutdegree":
                        echo '<div class="left" style="width:365px; float:left; text-align:left;">';
                        if($Developer['gender'] == "Male")
                            echo '<p>He has helped you to complete your code ' . $factor . ' times</p><br/>';
                        else
                            echo '<p>She has helped you to complete your code ' . $factor . ' times</p><br/>';
                        echo '</div>';
                        break;
                    case "recommended":
                        echo '<div class="left" style="width:365px; float:left; text-align:left;">';
                        if($Developer['gender'] == "Male")
                            echo '<p>He has been recommended to you by others ' . $factor . ' times</p><br/>';
                        else
                            echo '<p>She has been recommended to you by others ' . $factor . ' times</p><br/>';
                        echo '</div>';
                        break;
                    case "trustG":
                        echo '<div class="right" style="width:365px; float:right; text-align:left;">';
                        if($Developer['gender'] == "Male")
                            echo '<p>He has been selected (trusted) by others ' . $factor . ' times</p><br/>';
                        else 
                            echo '<p>She has been selected (trusted) by others ' . $factor . ' times</p><br/>';
                        echo '</div>';
                        break;
                    case "responseG":
                        echo '<div class="right" style="width:365px; float:right; text-align:left;">';
                        if($Developer['gender'] == "Male")
                            echo '<p>He has responded to others requests ' . $factor . ' times</p><br/>';
                        else 
                            echo '<p>She has responded to others requests ' . $factor . ' times </p><br/>';
                        echo '</div>';
                        break;
                    case "indegreeOutdegreeG":
                        echo '<div class="right" style="width:365px; float:right; text-align:left;">';
                        if($Developer['gender'] == "Male")
                            echo '<p>He has helped other developers ' . $factor . ' times</p><br/>';
                        else
                            echo '<p>She has helped other developers ' . $factor . ' times</p><br/>';
                        echo '</div>';
                        break;
                    case "recommendedG":
                        echo '<div class="right" style="width:365px; float:right; text-align:left;">';
                        if($Developer['gender'] == "Male")
                            echo '<p>He has been recommended to help by others ' . $factor . ' times</p><br/>';
                        else
                            echo '<p>She has been recommended to help by others ' . $factor . ' times</p><br/>';
                            echo '</div>';
                            break;
                }
            }

            echo '</div>';
        }



       ?>
```

If the output shows cases from the both the left and right divs, it works well. However, if the output shows cases in the right div, it shifts them to the left. I want to display them in the right and not in the right.

So, how can I do that?

The CSS is

```
.contectCode
{
font-size:15px;
line-height:24px;
margin-left:13px;
margin-right:13px;
border-style:solid;
border-width:2px;
border-color:#000066;
padding:10px;
margin-top:5px;
margin-bottom:10px;
}

.left
{
float:left;
width:60%;
}

.right
{
float:left;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your actual output html?

Answer (score 2):

how about :

```
.right
{
    float:left;
    text-align:right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ghadeer - I might be missing something in your post, but I took both of your HTML samples and your CSS, and tossed it into a quick page with the attached render (in Chrome v24, with colors to show layouts).  In both of your HTML samples, text in the right div is aligned to the left side of the div, because of the `text-align:left` in your inline styles.

If right-aligned text is what you want, consider adding `text-align:right` in your `.right` CSS selector, and removing your inline style from the `<div class="right">...</div>` element.

Much easier to maintain that way, anyway!

On a side note, considering you are generating that HTML verbatim, as it is, why have any inline styles in the first place?  It looks like those styles would be more appropriately placed in your stylesheet.

[image: Render of both HTML samples]

Comment: No, I need the align-text to be left. And, I used float:right because I want this div to be in the right side, but again the alignment in the left